# Disable a jqueryui datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jqueryui datepicker associated with a input text. When i make the input textbox readonly i dont want the datepicker to show up . Is that possible? I would be setting the readonly property to true or false from the code.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="CompleteDate"> <input class="change" type="checkbox" name="chkBoxb" id="chkBoxb"> </p>

</div>


j$('#chkBoxb').click(function(){
   var paramChangeBoxes = j$('input:checkbox.change');

 if (j$(this).is(':checked')) {

  paramChangeBoxes.removeAttr('checked');
    j$('#chkBoxb').attr('checked', 'checked');

     j$('#CompleteDate').attr('readonly',false);
     j$("#CompleteDate").datepicker();


 }
 else
 {
  j$('#CompleteDate').attr('readonly',true);
 $( "#CompleteDate:not([readonly])"  ).datepicker();
 }

});
```

Updated the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<div class="demo">
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="CompleteDate"> <input class="change" type="checkbox" name="chkBoxb" id="chkBoxb"> </p>
</div>

<script>
  $('#chkBoxb').click(function(){
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $('#CompleteDate').attr('readonly',false)
       .datepicker();
   } else {
     $('#CompleteDate').attr('readonly',true)
       .datepicker("destroy");
   }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: when i change the readonly property to false i get the datepicker but once i again change it true i need to datepicker to be disabled but it seems to be visible now. I updated the code in the question

Comment: @Prady, I see what you were going after now.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 37):

disable it like this:

```
$('#dateSelector').datepicker('disable');
```

and enable it like this:

```
$('#dateSelector').datepicker('enable');
```

Here's a  working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/CG64h/8/

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this today and unfortunately, the answers provided above did not work. Read the datepicker code, here's how it's done in jqueryui 1.10:

```
$(selector).datepicker("option", "disabled", true);
```

Comment: this may clear values in the datepicker.
which cost 1h to find out.lol

Answer (score 1):

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerDisabled.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use 2 different textbox's and toggle them as needed so that only one is shown at a time. The first one as plain text box and the second one with jquery Datapicker applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#").attr("enabled")=="false") {
  $("#").attr("disabled","true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the selector and add **:enabled**

```
 $( "#datepicker:enabled" ).datepicker();
```